# Problem with tasksel in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, 14.04, lamp, tasksel

I tried to install lamp server using this command: `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

But I always get this error:

```
Can't call method "set" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd.pm line 126, <GEN0> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $ret in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 132, <STDIN> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $ret in split at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 133, <STDIN> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $ret[0] in string eq at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 134, <STDIN> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $ret[0] in string eq at /usr/bin/debconf-apt-progress line 173, <STDIN> line 4.
tasksel: aptitude failed (255)
```

I tried to reinstall tasksel but with no luck

Comment: I get the same error on Debian 7.5 but haven't been able to track down a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Tim almost had it right- according to the tasksel manual, you can execute tasksel "tasks" using `sudo apt-get`, plus the caret:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^`

I had these same errors, the above command worked for me.